# C++ equivalent of fprintf with error

Tags: c++, c, printf, stderr

If I have an error message called by:

```
if (result == 0)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error type %d:\n", error_type);
    exit(1);
}
```

Is there a `C++` version for this? It seems to me that `fprintf` is `C` rather than `C++`. I have seen something to do with `cerr` and `stderr`, but no examples that would replace the above. Or maybe I'm entirely wrong and `fprintf` is standard in `C++`?

Comment: Please do not use exit (forcefully terminate a program)

Comment: @DieterLücking: Why not? As far as I understand, the code shown is C code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All [with a few exceptions where C and C++ collide with regards to standard] valid C code is technically also valid (but not necesarrily "good") C++ code.

I personally would write this code as :

```
if (result == 0) 
{
   std::cerr << "Error type " << error_type << std:: endl;
   exit(1);
}
```

But there are dozens of other ways to solve this in C++ (and at least half of those would also work in C with or without some modification).

One quite plausible solution is to `throw` an exception - but that's only really useful if the calling code [at some level] is `catch`-ing that exception. Something like:

```
if (result == 0)
{
    throw MyException(error_type);
}
```

and then:

```
try
{
  ... code goes here ... 
}
catch(MyException me)
{
    std::cerr << "Error type " << me.error_type << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You might have heard of `std::cout` in your first Hello World! program, but C++ also has an `std::cerr` function object.

```
std::cerr << "Error type " << error_type << ":" << std::endl;
```

Comment: printing to stderr like he does is also acceptable for the purpose.

Comment: Acceptable but hardly type safe. In my opinion, it's only justifiable if you have performance issues with your logging.

Of course, there are other modern C++ libraries that perform as well as printf while being type-safe and simpler to use than the standard iostreams...

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent in C++ would be to use [`std::cerr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cerr)

```
#include <iostream>
std::cerr << "Error type " << error_type << ":\n";
```

which as you can see uses the typical `operator<<` syntax that you are familiar with for other streams.

Answer (score 0):

C++ code rather uses `std::ostream` and text formatting operators (regardless if it's representing a file or not)

```
void printErrorAndExit(std::ostream& os, int result, int error_type) {
    if (result == 0) {
        os << "Error type " << error_type << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

To use a `std::ostream` specialized for files, you can use `std::ofstream`.

The `stderr` file descriptor is mapped to the `std::cerr` `std::ostream` implementation and instance.